# Group by array values in Presto

Tags: sql, group-by, presto

With a table of movies like this one:

```
genre               revenue
array<string>           int
---------------------------
[Drama]               10000
[Drama, Fiction]       2000
[Fiction]               300
[Comedy]               5000
[Comedy, Fiction]       500
```

How to group movies by included genre and perform aggregations, such as:

```
genre       count_movies    sum_revenue
---------------------------------------
Drama                  2          12000
Fiction                3           2800
Comedy                 2           5500
```

I've looked into the documentation for [array functions and operators](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) but couldn't find anything in that direction.

Potentially, the query responsible for this output would look like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS count_movies,
  SUM(revenue) AS sum_revenue
FROM movies
GROUP BY ARRAY_EXPLODE(genre) -- this is fake, just to illustrate the point
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `UNNEST`:

```
-- pseudocode
SELECT t.genre,
  COUNT(*) AS count_movies,
  SUM(revenue) AS sum_revenue
FROM movies
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(genre) AS t(genre)
GROUP BY t.genre
```

Comment: I applied the pseudocode to the example table. Sharing in case others find it useful.
```WITH movies AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            (ARRAY['Drama'], 10000),
            (ARRAY['Drama', 'Fiction'], 2000),
            (ARRAY['Fiction'], 300),
            (ARRAY['Comedy'], 5000),
            (ARRAY['Comedy', 'Fiction'], 500)
    ) AS account(genre, revenue)
)
SELECT t.genre,
  COUNT(*) AS count_movies,
  SUM(revenue) AS sum_revenue
FROM movies
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(genre) AS t(genre)
GROUP BY t.genre```

Comment: Darn .. couldn't figure out how to format a code block within the allotted 5 minutes of comment editing time :(